# DFSR and DFS-R tag merge request

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Can someone please merge these tags? People use both terms to ask/answer questions on DFS Replication.

Thanks
M

Comment: Makes sense... hang on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They've been merged. I even combined the tag-wikis because I'm nice.

Comment: I don't really understand the inner working of synonyms and merging, so perhaps I misunderstand what this means, but 
that's like merging Windows and Windows-7. DFS is a banner for two related technologies: DFS-R and DFS Namespaces. DFS and DFS-R are not analogous.

Comment: Also, the OP edited [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/338471/windows-2008-dfs-issue-files-dissapear) to contain the dfs-r tag after this was done. Shouldn't this have made that unnecessary?

Comment: I agree with @MDMarra - if someone told me to investigate DFS, I would not assume they were referencing replication and vice versa. Though close, they are distinct.

Comment: @MDMarra We're talking about "DFSR" and "DFS-R". Same thing, one with a hypen, one without. The "DFS" tag is still there with 129 questions on it.

Comment: @MDMarra I added dfs-r because it was more relevant. I removed DFS as there was no evidence of a question related to namespaces. And yes I wish people would use DFSN or DFSR specifically. But they dont and when DFS is mentioned, clarification is often required.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh. My brain somehow missed the R in DFSR. In my defense, @Dan missed it too apparently :D

Comment: @MDMarra sent me here and I just scan read it. I lose!